# Cannot access Salesforce textarea using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The Selenium Webdriver throws the Element not visible and cannot be interacted with error while trying to access a textarea

1.The textarea is placed inside a pop-up window, which I can access by switchTo(). I can access all other elements in the window other than the textarea.

2.I cannot find any "Visibility:hidden" tags for the element.

I tried sleep command, JavaScriptExecutor and also xpaths.This is the code I am using.

```
Set<String> handler = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterators = handler.iterator();
while (iterators.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterators.next();
}
System.out.println(subWindowHandler);
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='CodeMirror'] /div/textarea")).sendKeys("hello");
```

How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Try waiting for the visibility of the textarea first, using **WebDriverWait** like this: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='CodeMirror']/div/textarea")));`

Comment: I did try WebDriverWait,for upto a minute,but still the element cant be accessed.

Comment: Can you please provide a snapshot of the pop-up window where it has the textarea you want to fill ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent element of the textarea has 0 height. In my code I use JavascriptExecutor to manipulate the css of the parent element and then use sendKeys method.

The whole code looks like this:

```
jsEditorOperation("x[0].firstChild.style.height='1px';");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=‌​'CodeMirror']/div/textarea")).sendKeys(text);
jsEditorOperation("x[0].firstChild.style.height='0px'; ");
```

where the jsEditorOperation method can be used for accessing CodeMirror javascript API and its code is:

```
private Object jsEditorOperation(String code) {

    String script = "var x=document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror');" + code;
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverProvider.getInstance().getDriver();
    return js.executeScript(script);

}
```